# Unity C# - I want to play multiple audio sources on the same game object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a flappy bird type game and I want the character to make one sound when successfully passing through the pipes and a different sound when it hits the pipes or ground. So I have this code set but I cant figure out how to call to the separate audio sources. Seems to always just want to play the first audio source in my inspector. I have this script set on the game character.

'''

```
public AudioSource bing;
public AudioSource crash;

void Start()
{
    bing = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    crash = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("column"))
    {
        bing.Play();
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground") ||
    collision.gameObject.CompareTag("pipe"))
    {

       crash.Play();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't get two or more components of the same type from the same GameObject with the [GetComponent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) function, you either need to use the [GetComponent**s**()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponents.html) function or put the components on different GameObjects.

However, in your case, you should only use one AudioSource since the audio should come from the same place (the bird). You should instead add two [AudioClips](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioClip.html) and play those with the same AudioSource by using the [PlayOneShot()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) function.

Something like this:

```
    private AudioSource ourAudioSource;
    // The attribute will make the private field visible in the editor.
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip bing;
    [SerializeField]
    private AudioClip crash;

    void Start()
    {
        ourAudioSource = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(ourAudioSource);
        Assert.IsNotNull(bing);
        Assert.IsNotNull(crash);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("column"))
        {
            ourAudioSource.PlayOneShot(bing);
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground") ||
            collision.gameObject.CompareTag("pipe"))
        {
            ourAudioSource.PlayOneShot(crash);
        }
    }
```

Remember to add the two audio clips in the editor. The [Assert.IsNotNull()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Assertions.Assert.IsNotNull.html) calls are optional, but help you to find uninitialized fields easily.